# Cancellation problem: $R\not\cong S$ but $R[t]\cong S[t]$ (Danielewski surfaces)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I would like to understand why the two rings
$$
R={\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}/{(xy - (1 - z^2))} \\ S=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/{(x^2y - (1 - z^2))}
$$
are not isomorphic, but $R[t]\cong S[t]$. This example is discussed in [this document](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/Lip.text.pdf) by Hochster. He references a paper by Danielewski, but it is a preprint from 1989, so I could not locate it anywhere. In fact, this example was also given by Timothy Wagner in this [MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/does-rx-cong-sx-imply-r-cong-s), but no proof was supplied.

Finally, this [MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81971/about-why-danielewski-surfaces-are-the-counterexamples-for-cancellation-problem) seems to refer to this problem (though possibly with different formulation), but unfortunately it hasn't even received a single comment in the last 3.5 years.

Can someone either find a precise reference (preferably online, or at least published in some book/journal) or supply a proof for this claim?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, a good friend of mine wrote a [nice exposition](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~boblutz/essay_2.pdf) of this topic! Also, there is a very nice overview by Kraft: "[Challenging problems on affine $n$-space](http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/paper_file/Basel/Han/Bourbaki.pdf)".

### *R* $\not\cong$ *S*

There are two methods I found of proving this:

**Topological method** (Danielewski, [Fieseler](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-52245), [tom Dieck](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01190674)). Let *X*, *Y* be the surfaces in $\mathbf{C}^3$ defined by $xy-(1-z^2)$ and $x^2y-(1-z^2)$, respectively. Then, their fundamental groups at infinity are not isomorphic, in particular
$$\pi_1^\infty(X) \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, \qquad \pi_1^\infty(Y) \cong \mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}.$$
Danielewsi and Fieseler showed similar statements for the first homology groups at infinity; the former showed $H_1^\infty(X) \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ and that 4 divides the order of $H_1^\infty(Y)$, while Fieseler was able to compute them. Tom Dieck computed the $\pi_1^\infty$.

**Algebraic method** (Makar-Limanov). For $A$ a $\mathbf{C}$-algebra, recall that a $\mathbf{C}$-endomorphism $\delta\colon A \to A$ is a derivation if it satisfies the Leibniz rule. Denote by $A^\delta$ the kernel of a derivation $\delta$. We call a derivation $\delta$ *locally nilpotent* if for every $a \in A$ there is an $n$ such that $\delta^n(a) = 0$, and denote the set of these $\delta$ as $\operatorname{LND}(A)$. Finally, the *AK-invariant* denoted $\operatorname{AK}(A)$ of $A$ is the intersection of the kernels of all locally nilpotent derivations, i.e.,
$$\operatorname{AK}(A) := \bigcap_{\delta \in \operatorname{LND}(A)} A^\delta.$$
Then, Makar-Limanov showed that $\operatorname{AK}(R) = \mathbf{C}$, while $\operatorname{AK}(S) = \mathbf{C}[x]$. The former is simple to show, since
$$x \mapsto 0, \quad y \mapsto -2z, \quad z \mapsto x$$
is a locally nilpotent derivation with kernel $\mathbf{C}[x]$, and since we can replace $x \leftrightarrow y$ to get a locally nilpotent derivation with kernel $\mathbf{C}[y]$. The other computation is a bit more difficult; see Makar-Limanov's "[On the group of automorphisms of a surface $x^ny = P(z)$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02802499)". There is a nice textbook discussion of this in Rowen's *[Graduate algebra: commutative view](https://books.google.com/books?id=1AZfvv-Ava0C&lpg=PP1&dq=Graduate%20algebra%3A%20commutative%20view&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q&f=false),* starting at p. 201.

### *R*[*t*] $\cong$ *S*[*t*]

The idea is as follows, following Rem. 1.5 in [Fieseler](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-52245). Both $X$ and $Y$ can be realized as $\mathbf{G}_a$-principal bundles over the line $V$ with two origins; see one of [Prof. Speyer's answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/178554/33088) on MathOverflow (which is for a slightly different defining equation, but a similar glueing argument should work). Then, in the cartesian square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \times_V Y @>>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>>> V
\end{CD}
$$
all maps are projections of $\mathbf{G}_a$-principal bundles. Since $X$ and $Y$ are both affine, $H^1(X,\mathbf{G}_a) = H^1(Y,\mathbf{G}_a) = 0$, and so by Hilbert's theorem 90 (see Serre's "[Espaces fibrés algébriques](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/lmh/SerreArtikel.pdf)," §2.3), $X \times \mathbf{C} \cong X \times_V Y \cong Y \times \mathbf{C}$ is a trivial $\mathbf{G}_a$-principal bundle over both $X$ and $Y$.

I would love to know if the last isomorphism can be written out explicitly!

Comment: Wow, there is so much new stuff that I can learn from here. Thanks a lot to you and to your friend Bob Lutz! :)

Answer (score -1):

> M. Hochster, Nonuniqueness of coefficient rings in a polynomial ring, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 34 (1972), 81-82, [online](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/home.html)

Comment: At first sight, this example is different. But I suspect that you can make a change of variables.