# Domains such that $R[X] \cong S[X]$ but $\mathrm{Frac}(R)[X] \not \cong \mathrm{Frac}(S)[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Is it possible to find two integral domains $R,S$ such that $R[X] \cong S[X]$ but $\mathrm{Frac}(R)[X] \not \cong \mathrm{Frac}(S)[X]$ ?
>   $\renewcommand{\Frac}{\mathrm{Frac}}$

Here $\Frac(R)$ denotes the fraction field of $R$.
Obviously, $R[X] \cong S[X] \implies \Frac(R[X]) = \Frac(R)(X) \cong \Frac(S)(X)$, but it doesn't follow that $\Frac(R) \cong \Frac(S)$ (see [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96777) or [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448250)). So we can't conclude $\mathrm{Frac}(R)[X] \cong \mathrm{Frac}(S)[X]$.

However, the restriction of an isomorphism $f : \mathrm{Frac}(R)[X] \to \mathrm{Frac}(S)[X]$ to $(\mathrm{Frac}(R))^*$ has range lying in $(\Frac(S))^*$, and since $f(0)=0$ it follows that $f\vert_{\Frac(R)} : \Frac(R) \to \Frac(S)$ is an isomorphism. It doesn't follow that $R \cong S$.

That's why I think that a counter-example may come from [such examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13504). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355976). Let
$$R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(xy - (1 - z^2))}, \quad S=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x^2y - (1 - z^2))}$$
Apparently, $R \not \cong S$ (see the previous link). It looks like $R,S$ are domains. But do we have $\Frac(R) \not \cong \Frac(S)$ ? It would solve my problem. Or is there an easier way to solve it?

Notice that the "reverse" question is easy to solve $\Bbb Z \not \cong \Bbb Q$, but $\Frac(\Bbb Z)[X] \cong \Bbb Q[X]$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your example, $\operatorname{Frac}(R)\cong\operatorname{Frac}(S)$: both can just be identified with $\mathbb{C}(x,z)$, with $y$ being $\frac{1-z^2}{x}$ and $\frac{1-z^2}{x^2}$, respectively.

Comment: [Another example is given by Hochster](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3.pdf) for $R[x] \cong S[x]$ but $R \not \cong S$, where $$ R = \left( \dfrac{\Bbb R[X,Y,Z]}{(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-1)} \right)[P,Q]$$   and      $$   S = \left( \dfrac{\Bbb R[X,Y,Z]}{(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-1)} \right)[U,V,W]  \;/\; (xU+yV+zW)      $$       But do we have $$\Frac(R) = \Bbb R(x,y,z ; p,q) \cong \Frac(S) = \Bbb R(x,y,z ; u,v,w)$$?